# One or zero to many with code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is probably very simple and I'll end up with a red face...

```
class Person {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Person Manager {get;set;} // The person may or may not have a manager.
  public Guid? ManagerId {get;set;} // I need the Guid if the Person has a manager
}
```

I tried 
`modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(e=>e.Manager).WithMany().HasForeignKey(e=>ManagerId)`
but that didn't do any good.

Comment: Couldn't you get the Manager ID from Person.Manager.Id instead of using Person.ManagerId? Unless the GUID is something different in both cases I don't see why you would store it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried without any custom relationship mapping? I would have thought the ef would automatically do it's magic for you.

If not change you class as folows and you won't need to configure any of the relationships. It might be ef code first does not like guids

```
class Person {
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public Person Manager {get;set;}
  public int? ManagerId {get;set;}
}
```

Do you have a specific reason for using a guid and not int?

Comment: I need to operate with disconnected data, and guid seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using data annotations to help EF infer the relationship. Can't test this now so it probably wont work, but something like:

```
class Person {
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  [ForeignKey("Id")]
  public virtual Person Manager {get;set;} 
  public Guid? ManagerId {get;set;}
}
```